# CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation not able to product consisent result

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I am not able to get same result from CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation for two different coordinate system.
for eg.

```
CLLocation *tempLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.785834 longitude:-122.406417]; // coordinate for apple head quater
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];    
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:tempLocation completionHandler:
 ^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
     if ([placemarks count] > 0)
     {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];             
         NSLog(@" %@",placemark.addressDictionary); 
     }
 }];
```

### output    :

```
City = "San Francisco";
Country = "United States";
CountryCode = US;
FormattedAddressLines =     (
    "Apple Store, San Francisco",
    "1 Stockton St",
    "San Francisco, CA  94108-5805",
    "United States"
);
Name = "Apple Store, San Francisco";
PostCodeExtension = 5805;
State = California;
Street = "1 Stockton St";
SubAdministrativeArea = "San Francisco";
SubLocality = "Union Square";
SubThoroughfare = 1;
Thoroughfare = "Stockton St";
ZIP = 94108;
```

---

But when I use

```
CLLocation tempLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:27.672654 longitude:85.313744]; 
///CLLocation *tempLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.785834 longitude:-122.406417]; 
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init]; 
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:tempLocation completionHandler: 
 ^(NSArray placemarks, NSError* error) { 
    if ([placemarks count] > 0) { 
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0]; 
        NSLog(@" %@",placemark.addressDictionary); 
    }
}];
```

and the output is

```
{ 
Country = Nepal; 
CountryCode = NP; 
FormattedAddressLines = ( "Pulchowk Road", Nepal ); 
Name = "Pulchowk Road"; 
State = Bagmati; 
Street = "Pulchowk Road"; 
Thoroughfare = "Pulchowk Road"; 
}
```

The question is why i am not getting  all of the information. For eg City , ZIP .. are missing. How should i handle this issue in program.

Comment: Please put the code where it says "enter code here"

Comment: CLLocation *tempLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:27.672654 longitude:85.313744];
    ///CLLocation *tempLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.785834 longitude:-122.406417];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];    
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:tempLocation completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
         if ([placemarks count] > 0)
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];             
             NSLog(@" %@",placemark.addressDictionary); }}];

Comment: and the out put is

 {
    Country = Nepal;
    CountryCode = NP;
    FormattedAddressLines =     (
        "Pulchowk Road",
        Nepal
    );
    Name = "Pulchowk Road";
    State = Bagmati;
    Street = "Pulchowk Road";
    Thoroughfare = "Pulchowk Road";
}

Answer (score 1):

Geolocation is always using the best available information. Most likely for Nepal the mapping companies with whom Apple or its service provider contracted did not provide the information you are missing. This is more a contractual / service quality issue and I don't think there is anything you can do with it. Except trying to optimize your application to provide the best possible user experience even if it has only incomplete data.